# What's the expected number of iterations for this process?

Tags: pr.probability

Each step of the process consists of choosing a random integer between 1 and the last number chosen this way. On average, how long does it take to obtain "1" as a result of this process for any given starting number?

Comment: This smells a bit of homework, so I'll answer with a question. Let `$t_n$` be the expected number of iterations starting with $n$. How do you express `$t_n$` given `$t_1,\ldots,t_n$`? (I am assuming that $n$ is one of the acceptable choices given a previous $n$.)

Comment: This is close to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15162/hitting-times-for-an-n-dimensional-random-walk-on-a-lattice-with-strictly-positi

Comment: I actually know the textbook a question like this comes from. I've even assigned it in my class ! 

Comment: To make the question well-posed, it should depend on some large N = t_0 in HHO's notation.  Then you can ask for the expected number of iterations as a function of N.  But the first step, "take a random integer between 1 and $\infty$", is not well-defined.

Comment: It makes sense as stated. 